# How to run python github repository locally in my pc after commiting changes?

Tags: python, github, repository

I've forked an open source python project to my GitHub account and now after cloning it to my computer(on /desktop) I've made changed to it and committed the changes I made to my forked version of the original repository. But before I make a pull request I want to test out the changes I've made so to crosscheck everything is fine and working.

But since its a python repository and its located on my desktop, I can't import it and test as it's not an installed library(like we usually do i.e "pip install ").

**So how can I run a GitHub repository like an install package or library?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Nobody "runs a GitHub repository". That's not how it works. GitHub has nothing to do with running Python code. Your problem isn't clear. Specifically, what is your problem? "I can't import it"—well, is it supposed to be a library or a program? "[I can't] test"—you mean unit testing? Why can't you do that? Can you share some relevant code as a [mcve]?

Comment: (As a side note, normally you'd want to have some level of confidence that your code does what it's supposed to _before_ committing and pushing. I can't imaging writing code without at least trying it it along the way.)

Comment: I've figured out how to test the changes I've made, I can copy and paste those changes to my locally installed library then cross-check if it's working or not. I thought there would be a way to run a GitHub repository. Anyways thanks for answering.

Comment: Well there's probably a way to run the Python code _in_ your project. But, again, that has nothing to do with GitHub. It's like saying, "I thought there would be a way to run a Dropbox folder". If you provide a [mcve] like I suggested, or give us more information about exactly how you expect your code to run, we can probably help. We just don't have enough to go on yet.